# Update touch.position of gameobject instead of single touch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Pretty new to Unity and programming. I'm looking to update the position of my gameobject. At the moment the position of the gameobject is only updated when I do a single touch. Transform.pos = touch.position is not working for me.

Hoping for some help :) thank you.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlaceContent : MonoBehaviour {

    public ARRaycastManager raycastManager;
    public GraphicRaycaster raycaster;
    public Text m_Text;

    private void Update() {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // Update the Text on the screen depending on current position of the touch each frame
            m_Text.text = "Touch Position: " + touch.position;

            if (!IsClickOverUI(touch)) {
        
                List<ARRaycastHit> hitPoints = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
                raycastManager.Raycast(touch.position, hitPoints, TrackableType.Planes);

                if (hitPoints.Count > 0) {
                    Pose pose = hitPoints[0].pose;

                    transform.position = touch.position;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            m_Text.text = "...";
        }
    }

    bool IsClickOverUI(Touch touch) {
        //dont place content if pointer is over UI elements
        PointerEventData data = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current) {
            position = touch.position 
        };
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        raycaster.Raycast(data, results);
        return results.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is true only in one single frame ... remove it .. also rather use the `touch.position` instead of `Input.mousePosition` everywhere

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've updated the script above according to your suggestions. 

Unfortunately I'm getting a syntax error stating:
Assets/Scripts/PlaceContent.cs(23,16): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
Assets/Scripts/PlaceContent.cs(23,33): error CS1026: ) expected

 Not sure why. Hoping for some more assistance :)

Comment: You probably ment `if(!IsClickOverUI())` right?

Comment: ah, that confused me actually. I had that before but it was giving me a new error:
Assets/Scripts/PlaceContent.cs(43,24): error CS0103: The name 'touch' does not exist in the current context. Not sure why tbh. Could you tell me why 'touch' is not recognized anymore perhaps? Still learning a lot, thank you.

Comment: Without seeing your actual code it is hard to tell .. are you sure you have the correct amount of closing `)` and `}` ?

Comment: I think so. I've updated the original post above to show you the whole actual code. Perhaps I've made a mistake somewhere which you are able to find :)

Comment: Ah yes: obviously inside of `IsClickOverUI` you didn't define the `touch` .. it exists only inside of the `Update` method .. you can simply pass it on as a parameter like `bool IsClickOverUI(Touch touch)` and when you call it pass it in like `if(!IsClickOverUI(touch))` ;)

Comment: Thank you. I think that made it work in. I've updated the post above to verify with you if this is what you meant in your reply :)

Comment: Exactly ;) one last point: I thinking instead of `transform.position = touch.position;` (which would be in pixels) you rather would want to use the `transform.position = pose.position`